# Are locally integral extensions integral?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit and let $A \subseteq B$ be commutative $R$-algebras. Suppose $B_P$ is integral over $A_P$ for all primes $P$ of $R$. Is $B$ then necessarily integral over $A$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in B$. Then $x$ is integral over $A_P$, so there exist $a_i\in A$ and $s_i\in R-P$ such that $x^n+(a_{n-1}/s_{n-1})x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0/s_0=0$. Clearing the denominators we find an element $s_P\in R-P$ such that $s_Px$ is integral over $A$. Since the ideal of $R$ generated by all elements $s_P$ equals $R$ there is a (finite) linear combination $\sum_Pr_Ps_P=1$ with $r_P\in R$. Multiplying this by $x$ we get $x=\sum_Pr_P(s_Px)$, a sum of integral elements over $A$, and thus $x$ itself is integral over $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Presently I don't understand why the $s_P$ generate $R$. Could you please elaborate on it.

Comment: @ToddLeason If the ideal they generate isn't $R$ then it is contained in a prime (maximal) ideal, say $P$, but you have in this ideal at least one element outside of $P$, namely $s_P$.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.